# Starting Tomcat 8 service on Windows 7 issue: "Failed creating java"

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, tomcat8

Starting Tomcat 8 as a service on a Windows 7 computer for development purpose can be really annoying.

I had this error:

```
Failed creating java C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

And I saw in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin` that the `msvcr100.dll` wasn't the same file I had in my `Windows\System32` folder. In fact, in my `Windows\System32` folder, I had the `msvcr100.dll` that corresponds to the x64 version. The Tomcat service wouldn't start and told me that it is not a valid 32-bit version.

What I did to solve this was to install `jdk1.8.0_40` in `C:\Program Files`, open up `tomcat8w.exe` and under the `Java` tab, set the `Java Virtual Machine` path to:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\bin\server\mvcr100.dll
```

Now, for the Tomcat8 service, it would use the x64 DLL, and all work correctly.

My question is, could I replace the `msvcr100.dll` safely in `Windows\System32` with the x86 version instead? Or is my solution better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replacing lib is not a very good solution, because there are no guarantees that it will work correctly with other programs. I propose to just download a new version of this lib in a separate directory and try linking it to Tomcat.

Furthermore, looks like it is a known issue:

This usually happens because of missing `msvcr71.dll` file. However, Tomcat doesn't use `msvcr71.dll` directly, it's used by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

Solution:

1. Copy `msvcr71.dll` from Java's `bin` directory to Tomcat's `bin` folder.
2. Add Java's `bin` directory to Windows environment variable.
3. Copy `msvcr71.dll` from Java's `bin` directory to `windows\system32` folder.
4. Make sure your Tomcat is pointing at the correct `jvm.dll` folder.

[image]

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, as links can go down. I recommend that you paraphrase the essential parts of the answer into your post.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider in the future!:)